# Extend a range based on a variable in "pure" excel

Tags: excel

How one can create a dynamic range for extending formula with a variable number, without using vba?
The problem is that, certain column (e.g. column A) is dedicated to inputs (1XN with dynamic N based on number of filled row), and formula are needed to be extended as a matrix (MXN with fixed M).
Naively, solution seems to be for instance using `=TRANSPOSE(A1:AX)` where `X` is in fact number of filled rows in columns A: `=COUNTA(A1:A1000)`.

How could that be achieved withouth vba?

Comment: I think you may want to include a few screenshots of sample data with expexted results, just to clarify what you actually want here.

Comment: INDIRECT, INDEX, OFFSET functions may work for you.

Comment: For example: `=TRANSPOSE(A1:INDEX(A:A,X))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a quick solution would be =TRANSPOSE( OFFSET($A$1,,,COUNTA(A1:A1000),1) )
mind that for Office <365 instead of enter press ctrl+enter  (to make it an array formula)

but I would strongly advise to get a view of Dynamic Arrays in here or u_tb and see all the possibilities
cheers